# Using USB C 3.x cables with an E-mark chip for non-USB applications

Tags: usb-c, cable-assemblies

I was looking for a multi-pin cable assembly that is push-pull capable, shielded, has dedicated power lines and multiple twisted pair cables inside.  The idea is to use these cables to power peripherals (power supplies, analog sensors, comm. interfaces, etc.) that utilize multiple CAN buses.  USB C cables that are USB 3.x capable meet all of these requirements but I'm noticing a lot of them come with an E-Mark chip.  This makes me think that using all of the wires in these cables might require a little more consideration.

Below is a snip from a CnC Tech (P/N 105-1042-BL-00050-1) datasheet that shows the 'E-Mark IC'.  I would like to use the A5 and B5 lines as interrupt pins that are normally pulled to ground but could indicate a high level event (such as interlock breaking) when pulled to 5V.  How could the 'E-Mark IC' being inline with B5 and connected to A5 affect this capability?

Could someone provide some information on the typical electrical function of these ICs?

[image]

Comment: The e-mark chip is required for any USB C cables. If you get USB 3.x A to B cables, there's no problem, though you have fewer twisted pairs to play with.

Comment: @Hearth No it isn't required for any USB-C cable. Only for cables that go beyond 3A. And using existing cables for incompatible purposes is not a very good idea; someone will try to plug your devices to a standard USB-C device because it is possible and they think it's USB-C because it has USB-C connector. Connecting to a PC, phone or charger or whatever may kill your device or the standard device. A5 and B5 are surely **not** pulled to ground by every device, as that's how USB devices detect between UFP and DFP and charging current, communicate PD data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That no one plug it into standard USB at charger / PC and for orientation fixing , simply solder a small piece copper on it and cut the housing at other plug that it only fit into that one. (Don’t cut where the housing spring contacts are)
Or print and glue a small housing with a fixed M3 Screw or snap in nose on it so that it won’t fit any standard plug because the screw / nose blocks it.

Comment: Thia doesn't try to answer the asked question, but to some other question.